# Powershell - how to scan Active Direcotry for nested objects?

Tags: powershell, adsi

I have some **User** objects with "**ExchangeActiveSyncDevices**" object within. I also have some **Computer** objects with published **printers** inside.

So how can I look (with PowerShell) for such objects using some kind of unified approach? I mean without specific Exchange commandlets for AS devices and such. There must be a way to find objects with another object inside using some [ADSI] magic or such, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SearchBase of the parent Object to find Child Objects, for example:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter *|
ForEach-Object{
    $childObj = Get-ADObject -Filter * -SearchBase $_.DistinguishedName
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $_.Name
        ChildCount =  $childObj.Count
        msExchActiveSyncDevice = $childObj | Where-Object {$_.ObjectClass -eq "msExchActiveSyncDevice"}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use could try the Get-ADObject cmdlet to search for objects in Active Directory and filter the results using the -Filter parameter. The filter should be in the LDAP query format and you can use the -Properties parameter to specify which properties of the object you want to retrieve.
Probably like this:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter {objectClass -eq "user" -and msExchActiveSyncDevices -ne $null} -Properties msExchActiveSyncDevices
```

Comment: That's the problem - it's not property of the class, it's object within object. So this approach won't work